# could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, debian, postgresql, locale

Freshly installed Debian Jessie. I've installed: `aptitude install postgresql postgresql-contrib`

```
root@vps: createuser
createuser: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Why isn't it working? I've tried any single solution posted here: [Debian PostgreSQL doesn't appear to be working](https://superuser.com/questions/566592/debian-postgresql-doesnt-appear-to-be-working)

Not a single one works.

`/var/lib/postgresql/` is empty. `/etc/postegresql` doesn't even exists.

I tried running: `pg_createcluster 9.4 main --start`

But then I get this:

```
createuser
createuser: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
```

Or this, if I do it from scratch:

```
root@vps:~# pg_createcluster 9.4 main --start
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ALL = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
Error: The locale requested by the environment is invalid.
```

So I uninstalled, ran `unset LC_TIME` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40692507/how-to-fix-error-the-locale-requested-by-the-environment-is-invalid-during-po), reinstalled, but now I get the original error.

Can you please give me the set of comands I have to run to install postgres on a fresh Debian install?

EDIT: tried following the official guide [here](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/debian/). That also doesn't work.

```
root@vps:/# wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add - apt-get update
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

I'm really at a loss here. Is anyone even maintaining this stuff?

EDIT: tried reinstalling the whole server and running `apt-get install postgresql-9.4 postgresql-client-9.4` but got the same errors.

Tried to run this from [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/language-problem-on-ubuntu-14-04):

```
export LANGUAGE="en_US.UTF-8"
echo 'LANGUAGE="en_US.UTF-8"' >> /etc/default/locale
echo 'LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"' >> /etc/default/locale
```

problem isn't solved.

EDIT: I have tried this:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

and this

```
root@vps:~# update-locale --reset
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ALL = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

and this: `dpkg-reconfigure locales`

```
*** update-locale: Error: invalid locale settings:  LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8" LANGUAGE="en_US.UTF-8" LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the error messages indicate is that your system is configured to use `en_US.UTF-8` as the locale through the environment variables, but **it's not installed**.

Install it with

```
sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```

Once done, if `postgresql` is not installed, `apt-get install postgresql` will install it and initialize a default cluster with `/var/lib/postgresql/version/main` and so on.

If postgresql is already installed and a cluster doesn't exist due to the creation failing initially, `pg_createcluster 9.4 main --start` will create one. If in doubt about what clusters do exist/are online, check with `pg_lsclusters`.